# Grails: how to get intellij 14 to recognize that the version of a plugin has changed in BuildConfig.groovy

Tags: grails, plugins, intellij-idea

with Intellij enterprise 14.1.3 (and every version from 13 to date) & 
Grails 2.5 on Windows 8, Grails behaves very badly on a PC (seems to work find on co-workers macs).

We have complex project with a single application and 4 exploded plugins all happily loaded into intellij.  We can run it, edit it, it recognises all the dependences etc.

The problem is if we update one of the external plugins defined in a buildconfig.groovy, e.g.

```
    compile(":audit-logging:1.0.3"){}
```

to

```
    compile(":audit-logging:1.0.5"){}
```

Intellij still reports, and uses 1.0.3 - there seems to be no way to get it to recognise that the config has changed.

If we exit intellij, and on the command line do:

```
grails clean-all
grails compile
```

We can see it quite happily download the 1.0.5 version.

However, when we fire up intellij, it still says 1.0.3.

There is no 1.0.3 in any configuration file - intillij seems to be caching it, how do we delete initellij caches?

There is an option "Grails-Syncronize grails settings", but this has NEVER worked (on the pc, seems to work on macs), i.e. when you select this option, it simply does nothing - no errors, doesn't run anything, doesn't start anything, cursor doesn't even change.

Any ideas for a work around?

=== UPDATE ===

Apparently, grails uses ivy, rather than maven. However, there is nothing related to audit-logging plugin in home/.grails/ivy-cache.

strangely, there is a directly called .grails/2.5.0/projects/
Its strange because direclty under this are directories which are the names of the apps and their exploded plugins I have loaded into intellij.  In theory, If I copy the source to a new place, and fire up grails-runapp or intillij, there will be a conflict between the source in the old location and the source in the new location.

Even stranger, in this projects directory structure, are only copies of, and references to, the old 1.0.3 audit-logging plugin.  There is a copy of it below each of my exploded pugins, and in the app itself, with on mention of the 1.0.5 version.

It doesn't seem possible to upgrade a plugin version.

Comment: Latest Intellij(14.1.2) should auto-recognize the changes. usually when you change the plugin version in grails Build , a pop up will appear in intelliJ to uninstall and reinstall the plugin. try commenting the plugin, then, if the pop up appears, apply changes. Last, change the version and uncomment ,and apply changes as well.

Comment: Hi, I have 14.1.4 installed, and it has never done this, unfortunately.  The project synchronization stuff works for a simple no-plugin project, but for ours it simply doesn't work - there is no way to get intellij to recognise new plugin versions.  I am looking for some kind of hack, e.g. clearing ivy cache or similar, if any one knows of one.

Comment: try removing the empty brackets at the end.

Comment: @shaydel - great idea, but didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: can you publish your BuildConfig?

Comment: Same problem here, with a complext project with multiple plugins, intellij dependency handling for grails is completely broken, even with the latest 2016 versions